# Showing a function is non-surjective, non-continuous and increasing

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: [0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ be

$$ f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x & : x \in [0,1]\\
       x+1 & : x \in (1,2]
     \end{array}
   \right. $$

I can prove that $f$ is increasing. It is clear if we look at the graph that $f$ is not continuous and that $f$ is not surjective. But, how can I prove this rigorously?

Comment: To show it ia not continuous, perhaps use the epsilon definition. To show it is not surjective, pick an $x\in\Bbb{R}$ that is not in the image.

Comment: @Eoin, I think it is even "easier or faster", if one sees that $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = c $ and $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \neq f(c) $, with c = 1;
$ x_n$ strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is surjective if each point of its range has a preimage. In our case the range is $\mathbb{R}$. So take $4\in\mathbb{R}$ it has no pre image.
As far as continuity is concerned take the limits from the right and from the left at $x_0=1$

Comment: How can I show f is not continuous using the topological definition. In other words, how can I find some open $U∈R$ so that $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open. Can I take $U=(1,2)$ which is open. But how can I find $f^{-1}((1,2))$ ?

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: What if I take $U = (1,1.5) $, then $f^{-1}(1,1.5) = \{1\} $ correct?

Comment: $(1,2)$ is not the right open set to consider. Take $f^{-1}((\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}))=(\frac{1}{2},1]$ which is not open in $[0,2]$

Comment: $(1,\frac{3}{2})$ has the empty set as preimage because $1\notin (1,\frac{3}{2})$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = 5$ has no solution on $[0,2]$ showing non-surjectivity of $f$, and $f$ is not continuous at $x = 1$ since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^{-}}f(x) = 1 \neq 2 = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^{+}} f(x)$.

Comment: How can I show $f$ is not continuous using the topological definition. In other words, how can I find some open $U \in \mathbb{R} $ so that $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open. Can I take $U = (1,2)$ which is open. But how can I find $f^{-1}((1,2))$ ?

Comment: @BRIC_FAN, your last equality looks incorrect,
$ 2 = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^{+}} f(x) = f(1)$, is it (?)

Comment: @WillieRosario: $f^{-1}(1,2) = \emptyset$

Comment: which is open so that is not good.

Comment: I would look at $ f((0.5, 1.5)) $, which is not open. 
$ f((0.5, 1.5)) $ is defined, and open sets are mapped on continuous sets with a continuous function f. 
$ f((0.5, 1.5)) $ is not open, thus f cannot be continuous.

Comment: You are right. $f^{-1}( (0.5,1.5) ) = \{1 \} $ and this is not open!

Comment: @Imago I dont understant what you mean

Comment: What if I take $U = (1,1.5) $, then $f^{-1}(1,1.5) = \{1\} $ correct?